# class im.persistence.Line is not part of the schema for this Realm - when doing Instrument Testing

Tags: android, realm

The test (`testDb()`) runs fine if `Line` is in the test package.
[image]

However if I move `Line` to the production package, then the test fails due to an exception.
[image]

Any idea how to fix this ?

I cannot even begin to think what might be the problem here... really puzzling.

Here is the code:

```
package im.db_real;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


import im.persistence.Line;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DBTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    static private String safeToString(Object o) {
        if (o != null) return o.toString();  //+Test.getS();
        else return "null object ";  //+Test.getS();
    }

    static public Realm initRealm(android.content.Context context) {
        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).
                deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().
                build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return realm;
    }

    static public void deleteAllData(Realm r) {
        System.out.print("Deleting data...");

        r.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.deleteAll();
            }
        });
    }

    static public void createLines(Realm r) {
        r.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm r) {
                Line l1 = r.createObject(Line.class);
                l1.setTxt("line 1");
                Line l2 = r.createObject(Line.class);
                l2.setTxt("line 2");
            }
        });
    }

    static public void createLineList(Realm r){
        r.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm r) {
                LineList ll = r.createObject(LineList.class);
                ll.setName("line list 1");

            }
        });
    }

    static public Line getLine(Realm r, int i){
        RealmResults<Line> lines = r.where(Line.class).findAll();
        return lines.get(i);
    }

    static public void addLineToList(Realm r, final Line l, final LineList ll){
        r.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm r) {
                ll.getLines().add(l);

            }
        });
    }

    static public LineList getFirstLineList(Realm r){
        return r.where(LineList.class).findFirst();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDB() {

        Context c = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        Realm r1=initRealm(c);
        createLines(r1);
        createLineList(r1);
        r1.close();

        Realm r2=initRealm(c);
        Line l1=getLine(r2,0);
        Line l2=getLine(r2,1);
        LineList ll=getFirstLineList(r2);
        addLineToList(r2,l1,ll);

        r2.close();
        //    assertEquals(1,2);

    }
}


package im.persistence;

import io.realm.RealmObject;


public class Line extends RealmObject {
    public String getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }

    public void setTxt(String txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }

    public String txt;
}

package im.db_real;


import im.persistence.Line;
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class LineList extends RealmObject{
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name;

    public RealmList<Line> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public void setLines(RealmList<Line> lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    public RealmList<Line> lines;

}
```

EDIT:

The part of log of Gradle is here:

```
17:53:39.691 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Processing class Cat
17:53:39.697 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Processing class Dog
17:53:39.698 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Processing class Person
17:53:39.698 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
```

Comment: Do you delete the Realm file before each test?

Comment: No, I don't delete it. I can try that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Added `Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);` (also added the code to the question) , but it does not seem to help :(

Comment: There is an option in the configuration to delete the Realm file if migration is needed. It is very useful when writing tests.

Comment: @geisshirt that doesn't sound like the source of the problem, this would happen if during the build process, the class wasn't processed by the annotation processor

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so the problem is that the class `Line` is not processed by the annotation processor when it is in separate directory ?

Comment: What? No. I don't know why it doesn't run for Line. You can try throwing `@RealmClass` on it but I don't think that should be necessary because it's inherited from `RealmObject`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The exception is thrown when running the test. @jhegedus Have you tried to move `LineList` to `im.persistent`? And cleaned your builds?

Comment: @geisshirt Just tried it, it does not help.

Comment: It seems that the Annotation processor is working as seen in the Gradle Log (added to question).

Comment: The Gradle log doesn't mention `Line` or `LineList`. Did you declare any `RealmModule`s?

Comment: No, should I do that ?

Comment: That indicates that the annotation processor doesn't recognise `Line` as a Realm class. And then the exception makes sense. Did you try to add `@RealmClass`  to `Line`?

Comment: I try that, thanks for the tip !

Comment: Tried it, does not help :(

Comment: Actually, I think you're running into this: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3030 (you need to use getters/setters for instrumentation test to work because the transform API is an ass)

Comment: Hmm... I am using getters and setters already.